# How to access a directly-attached USB device (UltraLite-mk5) on a Raspberry Pi 4 from another networked device?

Tags: networking, usb, ip, network-adapter

I run Ubuntu 21.04 server (GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1016-raspi aarch64) on a Raspberry Pi 4 which is connected to my LAN through its ethernet port.

I have a MOTU UltraLite-mk5 soundcard attached directly by USB to the Raspberry Pi 4 so that the UltraLite-mk5 outputs sound streamed to the Raspberry Pi 4. I would like to be able to simultaneously access the UltraLite-mk5 over the network from my Mac in order to configure the UltraLite-mk5.

**Is there a way I can configure the Raspberry Pi 4 to allow the UltraLite-mk5 to be addressed using a unique IP address which can be reached from the LAN?**

#### Background

If the UltraLite-mk5 is directly connected by USB to my Mac, I can direct sound to the UltraLite-mk5 and simultaneously access the UltraLite-mk5 using control software provided my MOTU (CueMix5). When my Mac is connected to the UltraLite-mk5 directly, it sees the UltraLite-mk5 though the USB connection as a multi-function device:

1. firstly as a sound card device, and…
2. secondly as a network device through the Mac's network device en11.

So when directly connected, the UltraLite-mk5 is listed in the Mac's System Preferences | Network tab as connected with an Automatic Private IP address of 169.254.152.243. I've also noted that the CueMix5 app can connect to a UltraLite-mk5 over the network if given the UltraLite-mk5's IP address, but I've not tested that since I don't know how to connect the UltraLite-mk5 directly to the network by USB ... hence the question!

#### Potential answer outline

So I'm guessing the steps (none of which I fully understand!) will involve the following. I'm looking for help to firstly confirm that this sounds like the right approach, and then also help with what the right CLI commands are needed. So the plan involves:

1. **getting a second LAN IP address on the Raspberry Pi 4's NIC** (so the CM5 software can address that IP address from another networked machine). I know an NIC can have more than one IP address. I'd like to set up a second address, ideally acquired from the network's DHCP server (not sure if this is really necessary to avoid an address clash on the LAN), but the key thing is that this second IP address needs to work with the rest of the setup, in particular, step (3). For that reason, does this second LAN IP address need to be static? And what CLI instruction do I need to set it up?
2. **configuring a USB network service on the Raspberry Pi 4 to the UltraLite-mk5** so both Raspberry Pi 4 and UltraLite-mk5 can talk to each other. I can see that the MOTU software installation on my Mac for the UL5 creates a USB network service (called UltraLite-mk5) and if I knew the relevant CLI instructions for Mac I could examine what has been set up so I could reproduce it on the Raspberry Pi 4. But I don't know yet how to do this. Can you help me with this?
3. **mapping/routing/virtual switching (on the Raspberry Pi 4) that second IP address set up in (1) to the Raspberry Pi 4's USB network connection to the UltraLite-mk5**, so that network traffic addressed to the UltraLite-mk5's network IP is forwarded directly by the Raspberry Pi 4 via the USB network service to the UltraLite-mk5, and vice versa. Sounds simple enough! And if you know what the CLI instructions are, I guess it is. Help!

No doubt you can tell from my description that I don't have a deep understanding of networking, and I've only recently started to get to grips with the CLI of Ubuntu, so please pitch your replies at that level. Many thanks for reading.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi @Community I don't quite understand your comment as I think the question is very specific and detailed too. Is there perhaps too much detail? I'll add some signposting to see if that helps

Comment: @johnanon I copy edited your question to make things a bit clearer. The reality is your question is a HUGE pile of text. It reads more like an academic essay than a question. Additionally, it seems like you are using acronyms so much — like RPi4, UL5 and CM5 — that it makes it hard to read. This is definitely an interesting question. But the three part “Potential answer outline” is really hard to read. If you can, just summarize those three items into a simple paragraph that might improve this. The device sounds unique so this might not be a simple question to answer.

Comment: Would like to point out that if you do step #2 first, then the rest of the problem is no longer USB-specific or MOTU-specific, and just boils down to "networking between two network interfaces".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [usbip](http://usbip.sourceforge.net). It will forward the USB protocol over IP.

So you can install the server part on your RaspPi, and access it through whatever networking the RaspPi is connected to, under the IP address(es) of the RaspPi. It will not get it's own address (unless configure this somehow on the RaspPi, and give the RaspPi a dedicated IP address for it), but a specific IP address shouldn't be necessary, so you can probably skip all the networking steps.

It will also complete forward the USB device, which means you won't be able to use the device locally from the RaspPi.

The downside is that usbip clients currently exist only for Windows and Linux. So to access it from the Mac, you either can run Windows or Linux in a VM on the Mac, or you need to understand the Mac USB framework, and adapt USB (which is open source) to work with it.

---

If all you are interested is forwarding the sound, you could also use a [Pulseaudio module](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/) on the RaspPi which can stream over a standard protocol (e.g. ROAP/Apple Airtunes), and then access this from the Mac.

This should work out of the box, but doesn't forward the USB device directly.

---

Note that with either solution (and all potential other solutions) you'll add latency.

---

(Please update your question with the information you put in the comments about a network interface appearing and working on the RaspPi).

To allow access of the network interface of the USB device from the outside, you need to set up ordinary routing (all operations need root):

1. Both your RaspPi and your MAC probably got a DHCP-assigned private-range IPv4 address on your LAN. Find some subnet that doesn't overlap with your LAN subnet. For example, if your LAN subnet is `10.23.5.*/24` (the `/24` means the first 16 bits count, there are 256 addresses in this subnet), use e.g. `10.23.6.*/24`.
2. Assign an IP address from this subnet to the USB network interface:

   ip addr add 10.26.6.1/24 dev enx0001f2fff397
3. Enable forwarding on your RaspPi

   echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
4. On your Mac, add a route to this address via the RaspPi address. Let's assume your Mac got `10.26.5.12` and your RaspPi got `10.26.5.23`, then you do

   route -n add -net 10.23.6.0/24 10.26.5.23
5. You should now be able to ping the USB interface from your Mac (`ping 10.23.6.1`).
6. You **cannot** use the link-local `FE80::...` IPv6 address for anything like this.
7. There are various ways to automate all this, but for now, try to get it working manually.
8. I have no idea how a network interface like this would actually work to control the sound card. The [manual](https://cdn-data.motu.com/manuals/usb-c-audio/UltraLite-mk5_User_Guide.pdf) doesn't mention any details. I would expect a second network address behind the one assigned to the network interface, or some point-to-point interface. So while the above will allow access to a **network interface**, it may or may not work for whatever funny things they are doing on that soundcard.

If this was my hardware, the first thing I'd do is to run Wireshark on my Mac to see what is actually going on there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @dirkt. I can see what you're suggesting, but I'm looking for something else. The UL5 needs to be connected to the RPi4 and useable by the RPi4 via USB for the streaming part of my use case to continue working. So forwarding the USB protocol over IP would defeat that.

Comment: The second suggestion is interesting but not relevant to my objective. The sound streaming route is already well established and works exactly as I want it to, with the RPi4 working as a headless appliance, processing and passing the audio streams I send it to the UL5 for output. However, in my current arrangement, I can't control the UL5 and change its configuration. For that I have to disconnect it from the RPi4 and plug it in to the Mac's USB port. My objective is to avoid this plugging and unplugging which is impractical given the RPi4's location.

Comment: You cannot "partly forward" an USB device. For your use case, you need custom code that's accessible via network and does the controlling. Depending on what you need to control (which you didn't specify), maybe half a day or a day for an experienced programmer.

Comment: I've not said I want to "partly forward" a USB device, and I don't really understand your suggestion. When my Mac is connected to the UL5 directly, it sees the UL5 though the USB connection as a multi-function device: firstly as a sound card device, and secondly as a network device through the Mac's network device en11. Now when the UL5 is connected to the RPi4, ALSA is taking care of the sound card device connection, but there's no networking device connection established yet. That's the part that I want to set up. It's a question of how to configure the networking on the RPi4.

Comment: "secondly as a network device through the Mac's network device en11" please add this information to the question, because that's really unusual for a soundcard. In that case, it should show up as a network interface on the RaspPi (`ip link`, inspect `dmesg` before and after you plug it in). Once you've verified this happens, you can indeed assign it an IP address, enable forwarding on the RaspPi, and add a route on the Mac to access it. If it doesn't show up, use `lsusb -v` to identify the network function, then we need to find a driver.

Comment: Thanks! Some progress to report. With `ip link` I found enx0001f2fff397. Wading through `dmesg` I established that this relates to the UL5. So after `sudo ifconfig enx0001f2fff397 up` I looked for the status with `ifconfig -a` and I got `enx0001f2fff397: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::201:f2ff:feff:f397  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>` but no IPv4 address. Where next?

Comment: I thought I'd try `ping6 -I enx0001f2fff397 fe80::201:f2ff:feff:f397` but got no reply ... Not sure what to make of that

Comment: Thanks. Ping works as expected ... but after trying and then chasing up with the MOTU support team it seems I was mistaken in believing that the CueMix 5 app would address the UltraLite-mk5 device over the network. It can be done, MOTU support told me, from a networked machine running CM5 only if the UL5 is connected directly by USB to another machine running CM5. I've verified that this is the case. I also ran Wireshark as you suggested, but making any sense of what its capturing is way beyond me. I think I'll have to admit defeat on this one. Thanks for your help. It's been very informative!

Comment: The wireshark captures should at least show you how the software is (ab)using the network interface (which would be interesting to see), to get an idea what IP ranges they are using (if any), and what the routing should look like...

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler solution. Since CueMix 5 is just a Web application (Web page, if you like) that establishes a WebSocket connection with the UltraLite, it is possible to run a WebSocket app that runs on your Pi and relays messages bidirectionally between your computer and your MOTU. I was actually looking to do something very similar to what you are trying to do, so I wrote this simple node.js app that does the job: https://github.com/jpcarrascal/motu-ultralite-mk5-bridge

I think you should be able to run node.js on your Pi, so this solution should work for your case.
I hope this works, let me know if you have questions!

EDIT: fixed typo.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I read in [this forum](https://www.elektronauts.com/t/new-motu-ultralite-mk5-announced/151608/325) that, if your UltraLite is connected to a Windows or macOS machine, you can connect to it remotely using the machine's address (or network name) and port 1281. You just have to enter that in the "IP connect" area in the welcome screen of Cue Mix 5.